# JEE6 Tutorial samples not found

Tags: jakarta-ee

in this page of tutorial : http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnadu.html discuss about hello2 application on samples folder.

i download samples from this link and installed correctly:

https://glassfish-samples.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=5214&expandFolder=5214&folderID=0

but  "hello2" folder not on the "web" folder.

where is source codes for sun JavaEE6 Tutorial Volume I ?

thanks alot

Comment: Here's a similar SO question with some helpful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096189/where-can-i-download-java-ee-6-tutorial-examples

Comment: I do not understand why people like to close questions this much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the samples from http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/index.jsp (part of the Java EE 6 Web Profile SDK, the Java EE 6 SDK or [NetBeans 6.8](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html?intcmp=3513)).

You can also get them straight into GlassFish v3 via the [Update Center](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=V3UpdateCenterGettingStarted).

Just in case, note that you can also get  Java EE Code Samples & Apps from http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/code/

Comment: hi,but in this link http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/code/ i can't find hello2 application that discuss on JavaEE6 tutorial : 
http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnadu.html  
where is this application ?

Comment: I downloaded Netbeans 7.3. Where can I find the code to the samples?