# java ee http-basic authentication error page

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

Using the Form-Based authentication in Java EE to secure a web application,
we can specify a login and and error html page.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html

Example:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/logon.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/logonError.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Using the HTTP Basic authentication, we cannot specify a login page
because it is the responsability of the client web browser to get the login/pwd of the user (typically using a pop-up).

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

However, we would still need to specify an error page. Is that possible? how?
that is, using HTTP-Basic authentication (and Java EE), we would need to show a specific error page if the login/pwd provided are incorrect (as in the Form-based authentication).

Answer (score 4):

No, In BASIC authenitcation you can't configure `loginpage/errorpage`. This is how different authentication works:

**FORM Login:**

- Client makes request to secured page `/application/securedpag`
- Server sends `200 Status code along with login.jsp` configured in login-config
- Client fills `j_username` and `j_password` and submits to `j_security_check` servlet
- Servlet `j_security_check` is invoked on the server side, which validate `j_username` and `j_password`. `If authenication is successful, the request is forwarded/redirected to the secured page`. `If the authentication fails, the error page is sent` (which is configured in login-config).

**BASIC Login:**

- Client makes request to secured page `/application/securedpage`
- Server send `401 status code` asking the client to send `Authorization header with value containing Base64 encoded username and passowrd`.
- Browser will show pop-up asking username and password.
- Browser will again make  request to secured page `/application/securedpage` along with `Authorization header with value containing Base64 encoded username and passowrd`
- `If authenication is successful, the request is forwarded/redirected to the secured page`. `If the authentication fails, again the challange i.e,` 401 status code` is sent to the browser.
- Browser will again show the popup asking username and password.

  BASIC Login flow clearly shows that there is no where the response body is sent. Sever sends only `401 status code` for asking credentials for both first time or in case of authentication failure.

Comment: hello Ramesh; it seems a reasonable answer, but i am not convinced. :'-) how to be sure of this?

Comment: This is not quite right - 401 response may (and should) contain body. [W3 HTTP status codes definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) says: _If the [...] user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include relevant diagnostic information._

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP basic authentication error page is a HTTP 401 error which defaults to the servletcontainer's own HTTP 401 error page. Just specify a custom HTTP 401 error page in `web.xml`.

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/loginError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: @Baluc But will the browser show the error page in the background for 401 status code. I am thinking it will just show the popup asking for credentials again. Sorry i am asking because i have not tried this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the two examples here to be very helpful: https://svn.java.net/svn/javaeetutorial~svn/trunk/examples/security/hello2_basicauth/ and https://svn.java.net/svn/javaeetutorial~svn/trunk/examples/security/hello1_formauth/ . (You can check out all Java EE 6 examples via [Where can I download Java EE 6 Tutorial Examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096189/where-can-i-download-java-ee-6-tutorial-examples)) They demonstrate the two approaches you're asking about. Tip: For a newbie to security like me, I found https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ to be extremely helpful at sniffing around.