# Removing the resource name from HTTP 401 error thrown by Jetty

Tags: jetty

I've a webapp which uses Jersey and is running on Jetty.

Basically when I'm not authorized, and try to access an invalid resource or rest endpoint, I get the HTTP 401 error.

I would like to remove the resource name from this error which is thrown :

```
HTTP ERROR: 401
Problem accessing /login. Reason:

    Unauthorized
Powered by Jetty://
```

Can anyone help me by letting me know if there are any standard conf files which I can modify to prevent the resource name (e.g /login) from getting printed?

Comment: Have you declared either a Jersey error handling setup for status code 401, or a Servlet error-page configuration for status code 401?

Comment: Where is this usually declared?

Comment: If the 401 is from Jersey, use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26798284/775715 - If the 401 is from the web container, use one these https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066536/775715 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936707/775715 -