# How to find the netbeans RSVP Tutorial files

Tags: jakarta-ee, rest, netbeans, jax-rs

I am just learning JAX-RS and want to study the JAVA-EE examples on this topic. I am referring to this link http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipzz.html#gjvbc. It says that the example code is in

```
tut-install/examples/jaxrs/rsvp/
```

unfortunately i do not know where to download it from.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096189/where-can-i-download-java-ee-6-tutorial-examples)

Comment: The link from which the post is said to be duplicated is out of date. The answers all point to java.net which is no longer valid. The question should be accepted and receive answers with the current oracle address. I have the same question and I'd like to have the link to download tut-install....

Answer (score 2):

You can get the info
[here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gexaj.html#gexba) I guess you need to download Glassfish [server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/ogs-3-1-1-downloads-439803.html).