# Where are Duke's case-studies from the Java EE 6 Tutorial?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I'm a newbie to Java EE, so reading the Java EE 6 Tutorial. I want to examine complete applications, namely Duke's Bookstore, Tutoring and Forest Case Studies, which are mentioned in the tutorial. But I can't see the javaee-tutorial/examples/case-studies directory within glassfish installation dir. I've used the update tool and installed the Java EE 6 Tutorial component. It has downloaded other examples but case studies. As well, I tried to google, with no success. So where're these examples?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6096189/1341526)

Comment: check out this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096189/where-can-i-download-java-ee-6-tutorial-examples?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It's in tutorial. You have to [download Java EE6 SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html), then run Update Center and download the tutorial component.

Comment: well, I said I've already installed the Java EE 6 Tutorial component by means of the update tool. Some examples have been downloaded. But there no case-studies directory in javaee-tutorial/examples directory. Is there another way to get these examles?

Comment: I thought they are included. So now the only place when I think you can find it, is Java EE5 examples bundle. There are for sure. Hope nothing changed in it, but I don't know. http://java.net/projects/javaeetutorial/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is available in the below path
C:\glassfish4\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\case-studies  if you have installed glassfish in c directory in windows.
If not you have to download from the download centre here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/usingexamples001.htm#GEXBA